# How to mock relations on Django

Tags: python, django, mocking, mockito, pytest-django

I'm currently running into a problem, I can't figure out how to mock a relation.

Let's say I have some model called

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class RelatedModel(models.Model):
    my_model = models.OneToOneField(MyModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='related_model')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10
```

And I have some repository class like this:

```py
class MyModelRepository:
    @staticmethod
    def get_related_model(my_model):
        try:
            return my_model.related_model
        except MyModel.related_model.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist:
            # do some other thing
```

When writing unit-tests for this how can I mock the `related_model` to raise this exception or return some arbitrary instance?

Comment: I strongly recommend you to just make a MyModel without RelatedModel and this will raise this error

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it without `unittest.mock`:

```
class MockRelatedModel:
    @property
    def related_model(self):
        raise MyModel.related_model.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist()
```

If you do want to use `unittest.mock` you can use [PropertyMock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.PropertyMock). Note, this hasn't been tested. And frankly, I think it might be easier to create an instance of `MyModel` without the related_model set on it and call `MyModelRepository.get_related_model`.

```
with patch('path.to.MyModel', new_callable=PropertyMock) as mock_model:
    mock_model.related_model.side_effect = MyModel.related_model.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist()
    instance = MyModel()
    MyModelRepository.get_related_model(instance)
```

Comment: Ok! So I can mock a relation using the PropertyMock! Awesome! But what about using mockito?

Comment: I don't know. I've never used it.